# how to create a web player with ffmpeg and javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to create a web player with ffmpeg and javascript if possible the source code for the web player
without using adobe flash player or HTML 5

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything yourself? This question is too broad and it doesn't show any attempt at research or existing work.

Comment: last time I check we weren't on your payroll...

Comment: Edit your question and add more details. You question lack context and your efforts in finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[execffmpeg.js](http://www.uobot.com/execffmpeg/freeform.php) allows you to execute multiple consecutive ffmpeg commands with file piping in the browser, and then play the output video files in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Using ffmpeg to show videos in HTML 5 is a huge task. ffmpeg is not written in Javascript and you cannot use it for displaying videos in HTML directly.

However, there is a project named [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) that convert LLVM to javascript. Another project called [Videoconverter.js](https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/) uses it to convert videos formats in Javascript. But it cannot be used for playing videos.

Even if you can do it, it will not be efficient at all. Browsers that support Video tag use GPU acceleration, Flash uses GPU accelerations too. So the video play smoothly.

Comment: but I want a solution to create a web player . without using adobe flash player or html 5

Comment: Such solution does not exist. I think you did not really read my answer!